# Visual Basic 6 - when label changes, add/remove item in list

Tags: vb6

I am currently working on a Visual Basic 6 project called Starboy Notepad, which you can check on Github. I ran into a problem.

I have a RichTextBox1, Label1, and List1 controls. I've set that, every time I add a line to my RichTextBox1, the text in Label1 changes, displaying the number of lines in the RichTextBox1.

What I would want to do is that, in the List1, there would be added a time every time a line in RichTextBox1 gets added, and every time a line in RichTextBox1 gets removed, the last item in List1 gets removed too.

Basically, I want to do the line count you see on the left side in programs such as Notepad++ or Notepads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D (and credited)

Code about the line counter:

```
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lparam As Any) As Long
Public Const EM_GETLINECOUNT As Long = &HBA
Public Sub linecount()
Dim linecount As Integer
  linecount = SendMessage(Form1.RichTextBox1.hwnd, _
                  EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0)
Form1.Label1.Caption = linecount
Form1.List1.AddItem (linecount)
End Sub


Public Sub linecount2()
Dim linecount As Integer
  linecount = SendMessage(Form1.RichTextBox1.hwnd, _
                  EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0)
Form1.Label1.Caption = linecount
End Sub
```

In the RichTextBox:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_Change()

On Error Resume Next
Dim KeyCode As Integer
Form1.KeyPreview = True
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then linecount
linecount2
```

Like this it does work, aka every time I do press Enter, it works. But every time I do remove one line, it doesn't remove the last item from the List1 item.

Comment: Please post your current code and explain what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Done, but it doesn't really have a "code". I pasted the code that counts the lines, and the one that adds one item to the list each time the enter key is pressed. Problem is, every time I do remove one line from the RichTextBox1, it doesn't remove the last item in List1

Comment: Removing `On Error Resume Next` would be most helpful in trying to debug this and any code.

Comment: It's not a problem about this code, this code that I posted right here does work. Every time I do insert another row it does add an item to List1, but every time I do remove a row it doesn't remove one Item. The problem is, I don't know how to write that, every time I do remove a row, it should remove the corresponding row on List1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correct.
You have a side panel to identify each line in the file.

This panel always needs to be updated. Imagine the situation of a middle line being removed.
In your case you can simply remove all numbers and add them again.

```
Private Sub UpdateLines(linecount As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer

    List1.Clear
    For i = 1 To linecount
        List1.AddItem (i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, though it doesn't work because "Argument not optional". I tried to put Option Explicit between the parenthesis, at the end of the sub, at the top of the sub, at the top of the module, and nothing, even in the code of the RichTextBox too. I tried also to put that, every time the Enter key gets pressed, then it executes that code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: EDIT: thank you for your help, I've integrated this bit of code with the initial one, and now it works wonderfully.